# iPad orientation problem

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

In application i want to support only UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight. So i have done two things for that.
1) Set Initial interface Orientation to UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight in proj plist file.
2) writeen this code in each view controller.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return(interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

But when I switch to another view using removeFromSuperview and addSubview methods to replace the old view with the new view the new view is not oriented properly.

```
      How to solve this problem ???
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to your project's info.plist (this file would be in `Resources` folder) and add these two field

[image: I hope you know how to add fields]

You just need to add keys in left and the possible values will appear in right